# How to fix "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in discord bot

Tags: python, syntax-error, bots, discord

I am new at programming. I have been trying to make a discord bot, but every time I try to launch it it fails with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Code:

```
import discord.py
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

Client = discord.Client()
bot_prefix= "^"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Online!")
    print("Name: {}".format(client.user.name))
    print("ID: {}".format(client.user.id))

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await client.say("Pong!")

client.run("ID")
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Vanias>"C:\Users\Vanias\Desktop\MemerBoy\Test 3 bot 3.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vanias\Desktop\MemerBoy\Test 3 bot 3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord.py
  File "C:\Users\Vanias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Users\Vanias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .state import ConnectionState
  File "C:\Users\Vanias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import utils, compat
  File "C:\Users\Vanias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\compat.py", line 32
    create_task = asyncio.async
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Code is text, do not post it as an image.

Comment: You need to provide the full error message, not just the last line. You are using syntax new in Python 3.5, so you need to make sure you are using *at least that version or newer*.

Comment: `import discord` not `import discord.py`

Answer (score 1):

you have to put your bots token in
`client.run('your bots token here')`
not the id

you can google how to get your bots token

also check this [basic bot example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/basic_bot.py)

Answer (score -1):

try using this import
`pip install -U discord.py`
*sorry for the late answer lol*